# Image is not loaded when JavaScript inserts <IMG SRC=

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am adding rows to a table. For each new table item, the `innerHTML` is being set to:

```
picCell.innerHTML = '<label for="checkbox-a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a"
                            class="'+uncheckedClassString+'" 
                            style="font-size: 200%; width: ' +
                            tableCellWidth + 'px" 
                            id="' + checkBoxIdPreamble +
                            index+'">' + itemString + ' 
                       <img src="' + picurl + '" width="30px" 
                            height="30px"/>
                     </label>'
```

The `itemString` variable is the table item’s name and the `picurl` variable is the url for the user’s profile image that I get from their Google login.

It all works fine except that when the Javascript runs to insert the row, the user’s profile image appears as:

[image]

The console shows no error messages.

If the page is immediately refreshed then the image appears correctly:

[image]

Is there a way to force the image to be loaded as soon as the row is inserted?

Comment: All kind of loading errors are logged into the console.

Comment: No console messages. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should preload the image and then render the new row after that image has loaded. This way, you'll see the image immediately.

Additionally, you should create new DOM elements using the DOM API. This will allow you to not have to do the bulk of that messy string concatenation.

Lastly, you may want to set up CSS classes ahead of time and then just apply those classes to your elements, rather than using JavaScript to create inline styles (which should really be avoided when possible).

```js
// Generate the image element first
var img = document.createElement("img");

// Configure the image's style
img.classList.add("customImgage");

// Set up a load event handler binding for the image
img.addEventListener("load", makeRow);

// Set up a load event handling function that will fire AFTER
// the image is loaded.
function makeRow() {

   // Create and configure the label
   var lbl = document.createElement("label");
   lbl.for = "checkbox-a";
   lbl.setAttribute("data-form", "ui-btn-up-a");
   lbl.classList.add(uncheckedClassString);
   lbl.style.width = tableCellWidth;
   lbl.id = checkBoxIdPreamble + index;
   lbl.textContent = itemString;
   
   // Append the image into the label. At this point, the image
   // is loaded and ready to be displayed.
   lbl.appendChild(img);
   
   // Append the label into the picCell
   picCell.appendChild(lbl);
}

// Preload the image. After this is done, the load event handler will fire
// causing makeRow to run, which will create the label, add the image to it
// and then insert the fully ready row and image into the DOM
img.src = picurl;
```

```css
.customImage {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.uncheckedClassString {
  font-size:200%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll have a look. The code snippet produces errors when I run it....

Comment: @Todd You didn't supply all the relevant code, so I couldn't make a complete working snippet. I refereed to your variables, but obviously, they aren't declared here.

Answer (score 0):

Preload the image:

```
 var img=new Image();
    img.src=picUrl;
```

and add the src in the img tag.

```
picCell.innerHTML = '<label for="checkbox-a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a"
                        class="'+uncheckedClassString+'" 
                        style="font-size: 200%; width: ' +
                        tableCellWidth + 'px" 
                        id="' + checkBoxIdPreamble +
                        index+'">' + itemString + ' 
                   <img src="' + img.src + '" width="30px" 
                        height="30px"/>
                 </label>'
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This isn't quite right. If the `.innerHTML = ...` code executes right after the `new Image()`, the `src` still may not have finished downloading. The entire `label` code must be deferred until the `src` is finished loading and the only way to do that is by setting up a `load` event handler that includes that code for the image.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree, the same concept as progressive image loading. I'll try to update.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add a slash before the picurl. Try something like below

```
picCell.innerHTML = '<label for="checkbox-a" data-form="ui-btn-up-a" class="'+uncheckedClassString+'" style="font-size: 200%; width: '+tableCellWidth+'px" id="'+checkBoxIdPreamble+index+'">'+itemString+' <img src="/'+picurl+'" width="30px" height="30px"/></label>'
```